# Make normal lines finer?

Tags: normals

Quick question, how can I get these large outer edges finer, like the inner ones? The inner set of doors is perfect, the outer set is way to thick but it doesn't seem to matter what I do to them they usually come out exactly the same. I want them both about the same as the inner set. Bear in mind I'm a total noob with this haha

Cheers.

[image]

Comment: it may be due to the Margin value in the Bake panel, it just add pixels around the UV island, take a look into your UV Editor to see how the UV island overlap. If this is the case you don't need to worry as it won't be displayed on your low-poly

Comment: Woo that's got it. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

It's due to the *Margin* value in the *Bake* panel, it just adds pixels around the UV island, take a look into your *UV Editor* to see how the UV island overlap. If this is the case you don't need to worry as it won't be displayed on your low-poly.